# Formula to calculate how much to reduce a loan amount for PMT formula

Tags: excel, excel-formula

I have a simple spreadsheet that calculates the mortgage payment (using PMT) once user enters some key fields. I am also calculating the housing ratio (B9) which is the mortgage payment(B6) divided by income (B7). I am comparing the housing ratio to the maximum housing ratio (B8). There are many times when the housing ratio (B9) exceeds the maximum housing ratio (B8) and I need a formula in cell B11 that will tell me by how much I have to reduce the loan amount in (B3) to NOT exceed the maximum housing ratio in B8.

Can someone help me out with the correct formula?

[image]

Comment: Do the reverse calculation using the maximum housing ratio and then get the difference between the resulting loan amount and the current one

Comment: Not sure what you mean by reverse calculation. I am using the PMT formula to calculate the payment which requires me to feed the loan amount to the formula. I don’t know the calculate the maximum loan amount that will keep me equal to it below the maximum housing ratio percentage in B8. I am able to calculate by how much monthly payment I am short but do not know how to calculate what the correct loan amount should be to keep me at or under the maximum housing ratio in B8.

Comment: I think you want to look into the [`PV` function](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/PV-function-23879D31-0E02-4321-BE01-DA16E8168CBD)

Comment: PV formula is the solution, thanks

Answer (score 0):

Being that this is a pretty simple calculations, I'd suggest just doing it manually using iterative calculation.

First, enable iterative calculations for your workbook via File > Options > Formulas > "Enable iterative calculations."

Then, edit the formula for the loan amount to be `(sale price * LTV) - reduce by`

Doesn't take long the enter a few different numbers in for the "reduce by" to find it needs to be reduced by ~$6786.

If you want to make it a little more clear you can add another row under Loan Amount like so:

[image]